.NET 8 not inline read-only auto-properties
I'm checking the Disassembly Window, when running a long test, with a warming phase, that uses swaps, swap legs and coupons. The test runs the valuation code a number enough of times for PGO to kick in. I'm gonna show part of the Leg class. Coupon and Swap are similar. I should have shown Coupon, actually, but I have already refactored Coupon. This is how my properties are defined:
/// <summary>Represents a swap's leg, along with its coupons.</summary>
public class Leg
{
    /// <summary>Index of the first floating coupon in the leg.</summary>
    private readonly int firstFloatingCoupon;

    /// <summary>Gets the type identifier of the leg.</summary>
    public LegType Type { get; }
    /// <summary>Is this a floating leg?</summary>
    public bool IsFloating => Type != LegType.FIX;
    /// <summary>Is this a compounding floating leg?</summary>
    public bool IsCompound => Type is LegType.IRSComp or LegType.ZC;
    /// <summary>Is this the paying leg?</summary>
    public bool IsPay { get; }
    /// <summary>Is this a compounding leg with variable notional?</summary>
    public bool IsVNS { get; }
    /// <summary>Does this leg has a notional/fixed rate/spread schedule?</summary>
    public bool HasSchedule { get; }
    /// <summary>Does this leg use straight compounding?</summary>
    public bool IsStraight { get; }
    /// <summary>Initial notional of the leg.</summary>
    public double Notional { get; }
    // ... and so on
}

My project generates PDBs for Release. I run the test several times, and then I "Attach" Visual Studio 2022 to the process. I put a breakpoint in the code that's been repeatedly call, and when the breakpoint is reached, I switch to the Disassembly window.
The problem: all of the above properties are being called as methods. This is how the library's csproj is configured:
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <Authors>Ian Marteens</Authors>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <ApplicationIcon>bra.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <AssemblyVersion>3.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>3.0.0.0</FileVersion>
    <Version>3.0.0</Version>
    <Description>A valuation engine for IRD trades.</Description>
    <PackageIcon>bra128.png</PackageIcon>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>True</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    <IsTrimmable>True</IsTrimmable>
    <IsAotCompatible>True</IsAotCompatible>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    <Optimize>True</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>

There are neither references to ReadyToRun, legacy references to .NET 7 PGO, nor nothing similar. This is the configuration of the test (a Windows console app):
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <ApplicationIcon>bra.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>

Does any one have an idea of what is happening? Any help will be appreciated. My next step is to send code to Microsoft support, but I want to be sure first I'm not missing any stupid details.
Thanks in advance.
Auto-properties are not being inlined by .NET Core 8.

More context: each of the tests requires executing the code being watched for each coupon. There are nearly 500 coupons per trade. The method is called nearly 100,000 times in each iteration, so it's not a problem with OSR.

Seems to be properly optimised when I look on SharpLab

Thanks, Matthew. I'll try it on another machine to see if it's something related to any preview, and if that doesn't work, I'll ask Microsoft.
